# Android HttpURLConnection getResponseCode() 400 - why?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, httpresponse, http-response-codes

I had used below code for sending data to server in several projects and it works , but in my recent project it doesnt work and give me statuscode 400 ... i use this code in AsyncTask class :

```
public class sendingDataAsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        Integer result = 0;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        String key = params[0];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                }
                parseAdminTaskResult(response.toString());
                result = 1;
            } else {
                result = 0;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
}
```

Comment: 400 Bad Request. The server cannot or will not process the request due to an apparent client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, size too large, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Comment: You are not sending data in the above code

Comment: but when i send data via link in postman or even my explorer , it works ...

Comment: urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");   -- As you can se you have GET Request not a POST request which is for sending Data

Comment: so if i use "POST" method it works? i think as u said its because my data is to long ....

Comment: my url code is such as this: niroopajoohan.000webhostapp.com/hpws.php?req=create_new_record&record_date=جمعه 1397/05/24&record_time= ساعت: 22:04:57&record_w1=sdf&record_w2=asdf&record_w3=rftgh&record_l1=hj&record_l2=bn&record_l3=xcvb&record_w_score=&record_l_score=

Comment: It should work.

Comment: i found the reason and it was so ridiculous ... in my data that i wanted to send , there was space (" ")  ....... ):   im so sorry that I wasted your time ... excuse me ... (;

Answer (score 0):

Above code works properly ,but the problem was in my data that i attemped to send ... always make sure that in your data there is no space (" ") and then send it to server ...